# How can I catch event when a text field is exiting focus (on blur) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I look into TextFormField, the fields here isn't what I need:

- `onChanged` (called after each key pressed, I need when the user has already complete and exit the TextFormField focus)
- `onEditingComplete` (called after user press on Done key or similar, but user may exit TextFormField focus without tapping those button)
- `onSave` (called after calling `form.save()`. But I need to do this after user finish editing, to let user know that the app does "auto-correcting" to what the user entered)
- `validator` (also called on `form.validate()`, right before `form.save()`. not what I needed)

I need that when user exit the focus (dismissing the keyboard or tapping into another text field), I do a processing to let user see that their input is being adjusted and processed to the "correct one". How can I catch such event?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

By using [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) class,  you add a focus listener and can catch focus change.

By using [Focus](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus-class.html) class, you just wrap TextField and add a onFocusChange parameter.

**[Solution 1]**

- add a define FocusNode instance

```
FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
```

- add a listener of FocusNode at initState.

```
focusNode.addListener(() {
      print('1:  ${focusNode.hasFocus}');
    });
```

- add a FocusNode instance to TextField's focusNode parameter.

```
TextField(
      focusNode: focusNode,
    )
```

**[Solution 2]**

- Wrap TextField by Focus widget

```
Focus(
  child: TextField(),
  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
    print('2:  $hasFocus');
  },
)
```

**[Example Full Code]**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      print(focusNode.hasFocus);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return TextField(
      focusNode: focusNode,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ouu. I just only ever heard the first solution, but never the second. I think the second solution is the best for me. Thanks!!

Comment: second solution is not valid for textform filed

Comment: @appdev It works for TextFormField